# There is no effect on the image's display mode when I set the imageView's property contentMode as UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit

Tags: ios, uiimageview, contentmode

As the above description, when I set the imageView's property contentMode as UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit or UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill, the image on it displays like that the contenMode is setted as UIViewContentModeScaleToFill.

Comment: That may depends on the image that you are using.

Comment: Problem is solved. I resized the image somewhere leading to above problem.